# Rolling back a merge in TFS2008 with tfpt.exe

Tags: merge, branch

I need to roll back a merge operation in TFS2008. The branch will need to be merged at a later date. I know I can use the tfpt.exe rollback operation on the trunk to restore the files modified by the merge, but rollback doesn't modify the merge information so future merges from the branch into the trunk won't restore the changes undone by the rollback. Also, merges from the trunk into the branch will risk overwriting changes in the branch.

I've probably left out quite a bit of necessary information, so I'll update the question as needed.

What is the best way to undo the merge, and still be able to merge all changes in at a later date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this doing it manually and when you attempt to merge after after having checked out an older version and then checking in the older version the file is still essentially flagged as already merged.  I see the same exact problem when doing it without tfpt- pretty interesting.

So I took a look at the docs and it looks like what you are going to want to do is use [/force](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).  I am guessing if you do a tfpt rollback and then run tf merge it will work.  If not, try manually rolling back and then running tf merge /force.

> **/force**
>   Ignores the merge history and
>   merges the specified changes from the
>   source into the destination, even if
>   some or all these changes have been
>   merged before.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much! I completely missed the /force option on the merge. Sounds like it is exactly what I'll need. It will probably be awhile before I have to merge the branch again, so hopefully I won't forget this by then!

Thanks again!

Comment: Np happy to help and yeah don't forget :)

Comment: Also, after the rollback, merge the resulting changeset back into the branch with the /discard option. This will prevent the changes in the branch from getting wiped out if updating the branch by merging from trunk.